# Possible to keep max number of records in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Basically part of our Postgresql table is used to keep server access logs, and as such sometimes during production this can get pretty large. is there any way of setting in postgresql to have a maximum number of records a table can have and to push off the oldest record?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a trigger to maintain your desired row number:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trf_keep_row_number_steady()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
BEGIN
    -- delete only where are too many rows
    IF (SELECT count(id) FROM log_table) > rownum_limit
    THEN 
        -- I assume here that id is an auto-incremented value in log_table
        DELETE FROM log_table
        WHERE id = (SELECT min(id) FROM log_table);
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_keep_row_number_steady 
AFTER INSERT ON log_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_keep_row_number_steady();
```

This is probably not the best performing option, but once you reach the limit, it will never be exceeded.  If there is space for fluctuation, then you can check the row number periodically and delete excess rows from the beginning.

***EDIT:***
If you have really large logs (say a million per month) than [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) can be the easiest solution.  You can then simply drop the unnecessary tables (say where `max(timestamp) < CURRENT_DATE - 1 year`).  You can use your timestamp (or a derived date) as condition for *range partitioning*.

But be careful before discarding old logs.  Are you sure you will never need those?

Comment: we can execute it periodically, and we're sure we won't need them once the table gets big enough to require this, I'm just trying to automate DB maintenance as much as possible :)

Comment: also i was hoping that postgres could tell which one was older itself, but if not as we don't have ID's it could use our date created timestamp field "2012-06-22 17:17:52.692514"

Comment: @Jharwood - edited my answer.  Please tell me if you need further details.

Comment: +1 on the partitioning suggestion.  If you want to go with a count without the extreme overhead of scanning the table each time, you could use pg_class.reltuples for an approximatioinor you could use triggers to maintain a count in a "control" table.

Answer (score 4):

I created a more generic, table independent function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION keep_row_number_steady()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
DECLARE
    tab text;
    keyfld text;
    nritems INTEGER;
    rnd DOUBLE PRECISION;
BEGIN
    tab := TG_ARGV[0];
    keyfld := TG_ARGV[1];
    nritems := TG_ARGV[2]; 
    rnd := TG_ARGV[3];

    IF random() < rnd
    THEN 
        EXECUTE(format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s < (SELECT %s FROM %s ORDER BY %s DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET %s)', tab, keyfld, keyfld, tab, keyfld, nritems));
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER log_table_keep_row_number_steady_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON log_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE keep_row_number_steady('log_table', 'id', 1000, 0.1);
```

The function takes 4 parameters:

- tab: table name
- keyfld: numeric, progressive key field
- nritems: number of items to retain
- rnd: random number, from 0 to 1; the bigger it is, the more frequent table will be cleaned (0=never, 1=always, 0.1=10% of times)

This way you can create how many triggers you want calling the same function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I created this proc and run it from PG Agent (or windows job or cron job depending). I can have more rows, this just keeps my log table not too big. Saves the overhead of a trigger.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION activitylogcleanup(_MaxRows int) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
   minid    int;
BEGIN
    SELECT logid into minid FROM activitylogapplication 
     order by logid desc limit 1 OFFSET _MaxRows;

    if not found then 
        return;
    END IF; 

    Delete from activitylogapplication where logid < minid;
END;
$$;
```